# Database query INSERT INTO is failing

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble with my database query, with which everything seems to be alright, but still the query is failing. I am trying to pass email and password through a registration form.

Here is my database query code:

```
public static function add_user($email, $password){
    global $database;

    $password = password_krypt($password);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "users (email, password)  
    VALUES ('" . $email . "', '". $password ."')";

    $result = $database->query($sql);

    if(!$result) {
        return pd("Error! DB query: " . $sql);
    }
    return "OK";
}
```

Here is the code of the file where I am calling out the query:

```
elseif ($btn === 'add') {
        $result = User::add_user($password, $email);
        if($result == 'OK') {
            echo 'User added to database!';
            redirect_to('/user/list.php');
        } else {
            echo $result;
        }
```

The code of the form itself:

```
<form method="post">
                <?php echo form_input('email', 'email', 'Sisestage email', 'Email',  empty($user_from_db['email']) ? $email : $user_from_db['email']); ?>
                <?php echo form_input('password', 'password', 'Enter your password', 'Password'); ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button name="btn" value="add" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create an account</button>
                    <button name="btn" value="edit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Edit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

And finally the error, which is given points to my MySQL Database connection file, which has different functions and the error is pointing to the confirm_query function.

```
public function query($sql) {
    $this->last_query = $sql;
    $result = $this->connection->query($sql);
    $this->confirm_query($result);

    pd($result);

    return $result;
}

private function confirm_query($result) {
    if(!$result) {
        $r = "Database query failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        $r.= "<p>SQL: {$this->last_query}</p>";
        die($r);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: No error whatsoever, just says Database Query Failed: and then the SQL query, which is stated in the confirm_query function.

Comment: Maybe double check you have the database name, password and username correct?

Comment: You are using `mysqli_connect_error()`. Try [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) instead.

Comment: Everything has been checked multiple times, they are indeed correct.

Comment: Tried using mysqli_error instead and it gave me this error: Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given.

Comment: What variable did you pass to mysqli_error? If you used `$database` from global, than there is indeed something wrong with the connection.

Comment: I passed the $result variable to it. The database connection is fine, because i also have some select statements, which work perfectly.

Comment: @MikkP that's not how mysqli_error works. It takes `link` as paramenter (aka the connection). You didn't even look for how that function is supposed to be used xD. Please, fix that and let us know the output

Comment: My bad, fixed the variable and issued the correct variable to it, but still nothing has changed. The output is same as with mysqli_connect_error().

Comment: Try copying the query to a panel (such as phpmyadmin) and see if you get any errors from there.

Comment: Yes!! Got the issue solved, the problem was that I had a couple of other columns in the table and they didn't have a default value assigned. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score -3):

stop using double quotes inside values..that might solve your problem and keep ur query as simple as possible